# How large does the interval need to be?

Tags: normal-distribution

can anyone help with this question

Q: According to a survey of 10000 students, the average distance to the university is 22 minutes with a standard deviation of 5 minutes (normally distributed).
a) Plot (sketch) the distribution including all relevant labels.
b) How likely is it that a randomly sampled student has a distance between 15 and 25 minutes?
c) How large does the interval need to be, so that a randomly samples student belongs to the 95% (99%) of the most probable distances?

so far i have done
sol:: i have plotted a graph that ie most likely to fall under the 95 % 
if we standardize the sample mean then we can directly see in which probability area in which it lies 
let say we have a z score 2.5 it outside of the most unlikely events under the distribution this would called significance unit

Comment: Add the `self-study` tag and read the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[image: This would be your chart]

For the second question just do:

- The cumulative distribution until 25 minus the cumulative distribution until 15. So answer would be 64,5%

For the last question you need to know that on a normal distribution 95% of the values are within 2 standard deviations and 99,7% of the cases are withing 3 standard deviations.

Comment: thank u so much